# If I find a hidden number, do I have to be on the tile to replace it?

Tags: the-7th-continent

Say that I notice a hidden number on a tile on the other side of the continent. Do I still replace the tile card even though I am nowhere near it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules don't say anything about needing a figure on the card (or on the connected terrain card for permanent event cards).

> Some Terrain and Permanent event cards contain hidden numbers. When players find one, they may discard the card on which they spotted it and replace it with the card bearing that number.

From what I've seen, hidden cards open new paths or new actions, so you won't be able to take advantage of these until you have a figure on the card. This means that little is gained from revealing the hidden card without a figure on the card (or on the connected terrain card for permanent event cards), so it makes little difference if you reveal the hidden card sooner rather than later.

Since it makes little difference, you may want to wait to reveal the hidden card until you have a figure on the card or an adjacent one for thematic reasons (since the hidden card represents keen observation or exceptional situational problem solving on the part of your character). But you are not required to do so.